# Use GD or any other php library to build a workflow

Tags: php, image, workflow, imagemagick, gd

I am developing a sports website that would be keeping a record of all tournaments in tennis, football and rugby. Now my database structure is built to hold who plays who in which tournament, so it would just be a select to display all the information. The type of workflow that I am talking about is the one that is commonly used in the sports arena where players' names are listed head to head, and the level of that match(knockout,quater final, semifinal, etc.) are also listed. I do not know the correct term for this though. I will give you an example for how it would look.

[image]

I am sure this is possible by using web technology, I am just finding it hard on where to start. Any advice or suggestions are much appreciated. Also if there are any libraries I could use for this, that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: There may be some geographical differences, but I'd call that a "bracket."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you want to format the information you should be able to do it in a few ways.

You could use GD like you mentioned but that may be a bit tedious once you get larger and larger brackets. (I don't have a lot of exp. with GD but I know the basics)

I have implemented a 256 person ladder or bracket using html and css.  This proved to be pretty simple to do and it should be able to scale easily and be easy to make changes to.

Comment: Ryan how would the css look like?? Getting the data should not be hard but what would your suggestion be for aligning the opponents top and bottom and then define the next stage, and other players in the same level??

Comment: I am currently at work. When I get home I will post an example of how you can align everything.

Comment: Here is an example of one from a site I found online a while back  http://jsfiddle.net/NERK6/2/  Edit: Fixed url

Answer (score 0):

Well on a first glance I would see the following data:

- Teams
- Cups (having Rounds)
- Rounds (of Matches)
- Matches (of Teams)

You could model that into a relational database, e.g. MySQL.

You can then create models in classes for your application, e.g. in PHP.

You can then create a Web UI to display the data you've entered into the database. You can use GD for that (if it's a need, I think HTML is not that bad for that, would do it with simple text based output *first* before turning everything into an image).

Maybe that's helpful. Was a bit lengthy for a comment, so I added it as an answer.